# sending multiple jMS messages at once with maintaining sequence

Tags: java, jms, activemq-classic

I am using Java, spring-boot and ActiveMQ. 
I need to send a large bunch of messages in shortest time.
Right now it takes lot of time to send message one by one using JMSTemplate.

Is there any way I can bunch the messages and send if to activemq at once with guarantee to maintain the order of messages?

thanks in advance

Comment: can you post your AMQConnectionFactory config

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Default ActiveMQ configuration can be slow for large message flow. We use following configuration for improving the message rates -

```
connection.setOptimizeAcknowledge(true);
consumerSession = connection.createSession(false, Session.DUPS_OK_ACKNOWLEDGE);
```

`setOptimizeAcknowledge` configures optimized acknowledgement of received messages while `Session.DUPS_OK_ACKNOWLEDGE` allows batched acknowledgements.

Comment: additionally this can be optimized by managing the ActiveMQConnectionFactory.setSessionTaskRunner & ActiveMQConnectionFactory.useAsyncSend = true

Answer (score 1):

Spring's JMSTemplate is notorious for bad performance outside a Java EE container (or some other environment which provides pooled connection resources). Read more on the [Apache ActiveMQ website](http://activemq.apache.org/jmstemplate-gotchas.html). Therefore, you need to use a connection pool or ditch the JMSTemplate for something else.